# Can't copy cells in protected cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have one doubt in excel I just protect some cells in excel for editing formulas and all but I can't copy & paste same cells to same excel page. Any option to do same?? Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy and paste a cell you need to make sure that the target cell is not locked if the target sheet is protected.

Your question is not very clear, but conceptually it works like this:

- format cells you want to protect by turning on the "Locked" property in the "Protection" tab of the Format Cell dialog.
- Turn on sheet protection with "Review" > "Protect Sheet". There are many options that you can select here, so take a look at these options and select what you want. If you stick with the defaults you can
- select a protected cell and copy it
- paste the cell somewhere else, provided that the target of the paste is not a protected cell in a locked sheet.

If that does not reflect what you want to do, please **update your question** and post a comment when you have done so.